# MATLAB - Help speed up the code

Tags: performance, matlab, nested-loops, matrix-multiplication

I need your help to speed up my MATLAB code. Line 17 is the most expensive part. It is because of the two nested loops. I need help with removing the loops and rewrite it into just one matrix multiplication expression. Note that I have taken dKdx as a cell, which is causing problems to replace nested loops with simple matrix multiplication term. Any ideas?
Below if a simplified code. May be dKdx doesn't need to be an cell? Idea behind cell was to be able to store lot of matrices of size [2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1)].

```
    clc
    nelx = 16; nely = 8;
    dKdx = cell(2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),1);
    Hess = zeros(nelx*nely,nelx*nely);
    U = rand(2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),1);
    dUdx = rand(2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),nelx*nely);

    for elx = 1:nelx
        for ely = 1:nely
            elm = nely*(elx-1)+ely;               
            dKdx{elm,1} = rand(2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1),2*(nelx+1)*(nely+1));
        end
    end

    for i = 1:nelx*nely    
        for j = i:nelx*nely
            Hess(i,j) = U'*dKdx{j,1}*dUdx(:,i);
            if i ~= j
                Hess(j,i) = Hess(i,j);
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Probably better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the Hess loop is what you want to optimize, it would be clearer if you could distill the code to the bare essential, and say that Hess is a nx*ny by nx*ny matrix, U is a 2*(nx+1)(ny+1) vector, etc...

Comment: ya you are right. I wanted to give some background for my problem. But it seems like all that is unnecessary. I will simplify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to get it:

```
  B = reshape(U'*cell2mat(dKdx'),[size(U,1) nelx*nely]);
  C = B'*dUdx;
  Hess=tril(C)+triu(C',1);
```

In my machine this code runs 6-7 times faster than the for loop one. I wonder if there are other even faster ways...

Comment: thanks but its the upper/lower triangle calculation which is the expensive part $Hess(i,j) = -2*U'*dKdx{j,1}*dUdx(:,i);$.. Rest (diagonal addition, and adding lower triangle) is negligible..

Comment: Are you really asking me something you can answer in a few seconds yourself?  try and see, you just need to copy paste it.

Comment: I did copy and paste it! It turns out that it gives a different result for John's original code (which is what I was still using), but give the same result for the code that is now there. Not sure why.

Comment: Ah, it's because he dropped the -2 in front of the U.

Comment: thanks both you guys.. this helps a lot. nate quick question. Why is the third line needed? Isn't C already the hessian I need, according the matrix multiplication formulas? I see that the "Hess" from your code is closer to "Hess" from my code than "C". How do you justify the third line?

Comment: C is not the Hessian because it is not symmetric. (doesn't fulfill H(i,j)=H(j,i)). In your code you had to test if i~=j and then force the symmetry. The code I wrote does the same . You can test for symmetry quickly by using isequal(C,C.') and see... (vs the Hess).

Comment: I was checking for symmetry because I wanted to reduce the number of matrix multiplication. That is the only reason to test i~=j, so that I do only half the calculations.But you are explicitly forcing symmetry.

Comment: The matrix multiplication is equivalent to using a loop with j=1:nelx*nely, however you only run the nested loop from j = i:nelx*nely .  If you run from j=1:nelx*nely instead, you'll get the same matrix as C, but then Hess won't be symmetric... imagesc(Hess) in that case and see.

Comment: I did what you asked. Turns out C = Hess' for j = i:nelx*nely. That is weird.

Comment: Why is it weird, because it is Hess' ? then just define C=dUdx'*B, the argument stands that Hess is not symmetric if you go to the full loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18259/discussion-between-john-smith-and-nate)

Answer (score 2):

It may not be surprising that the hessian is the bottleneck. You have to calculate O(n^2) matrix elements, and you are doing O(n^3) work per matrix element, so that's O(n^5), which is worse than inverting the matrix (unless I am misunderstanding your code).

Having said that, it seems like you should be able to replace the `dKdx{j,1}*dUdx(:,i)` matrix/vector multiplication in the inner loop with a single matrix/matrix multiplication `dKdx{j,1}*dUdx` in the outer loop, then just pull out the particular column that you need in the inner loop (you would need to `j` first too). I don't have time to try this myself right now, but perhaps it will help you.

Another thought: are you sure there isn't some structure in your matrices that you can take advantage of to reduce the number of matrix multiplies?

**Update**

In the process of trying to make my idea work, I came up with the following:

```
Hess2 = zeros(nelx*nely,nelx*nely);
for j=1:nelx*nely
    Hess2(j,:) = U'*dKdx{j,1}*dUdx;
end
Hess2 = tril(Hess2)+triu(Hess2',1);
```

On my machine this is 25 times faster, but Nate's is 80 times faster, so he beats me!